# XAMPP doesn't respond on Windows 7 host

Tags: windows-7, xampp

I just uninstalled WAMP on Windows 7 because I have been getting an error when I install an application (I think not compatible to WAMP's MySQL).

So I installed XAMPP on Windows 7 - I get no errors but when I point my server to `localhost` it just keeps loading with no response. XAMPP and the application are working fine on Windows XP.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=37143) suggests that Windows 7 runs it's own process on port 80 which will conflict with Apache. The suggested solution is to install Apache as a service and then restart. Alternately, you can disable http.sys. You can shut it down from the command line with `net stop http`. [This page](http://www.cameroncooke.com/2009/01/25/windows-7-uses-port-80-and-makes-it-impossible-to-install-apache-solution/) has a permanent solution:

1. Start regedit (Start -> Run -> Type "regedit")
2. Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP
3. Add a new DWORD (32-bit) value
4. Name it ‘NoRun’ not including the quotes
5. Double click the new property
6. In the Value data field type ‘1′ not including quotes and click OK
7. Re-boot your computer